# Import from a template folder containg the characters {{

Tags: python, pytest

I have created a cookiecutter template. The folder of the template is named as `{{cookicutter.project_slug}}`. Inside this folder, I have the script `make_repository_structure.py` that creates the necessary structure dependent on the repository application type (i.e., a Python package, data science project, etc.). The template repository has the following structure

```bash
.
|- {{cookicutter.project_slug}}/
|   |- make_repository_structure.py
|
|- tests/
    |- test_make_repository_structure.py
```

What I am trying to do is to design a test that verify if this repository structure is correctly implemented. I want to use Pytest to do this, and I wrote the file `test_make_repository_structure.py` that starts with

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import pytest

PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).parents[1].resolve()

sys.path.append(str(PROJECT_ROOT))

mrs = __import__(r"{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")


def test_error_on_invalid_repository_type():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        mrs.make_repository_structure.main("invalid_repository_type")
```

When I run this script with Pytest, I get the following error:

```bash
pytest
============================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /workspaces/python.template, configfile: pyproject.toml, testpaths: tests
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                  

=================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================
__________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_make_repository_structure.py __________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/workspaces/python.template/tests/test_make_repository_structure.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/home/python.template/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_make_repository_structure.py:10: in <module>
    mrs = __import__(r"{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '{{cookiecutter'
========================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================
ERROR tests/test_make_repository_structure.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================== 1 error in 0.08s ==============================================================================
```

From the error, it looks that the import having an issue with the `.` character. I am aware that the naming convention for imports is not the best, but I ran out of ideas on how to solve this. Does someone have an idea to tackle this issue?

Many thanks,

Ps.: I am running Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, all of the proposed solutions did not work for me.

The workaround that I have found is to append to the `sys.path` as follows

```
sys.path.append("{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")

import bin.make_repository_structure as mrs
```

Then, the import was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `importlib.import_module` function to import the the module:

```
import importlib

mrs = importlib.import_module("{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")
```

This should fix the error `ModuleNotFound`

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it still raises the same error. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can try use:

```
import importlib
mrs = importlib.import_module("{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")
```

instead of:

```
mrs = __import__(r"{{cookiecutter.project_slug}}")
```

Hope this helps.

[ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)